# Wordpress Page and Custom Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having an irritating problem with my Wordpress site I was hoping you might be able to help me with.

Basically, I have a page - Case Studies, which was called 'case-studies' in the nav structure. It was later removed and re-added, forcing it to 'case-studies-2'. Is there any way of editing this? I tried changing the permalink within the page itself but it reverts to 'case-studies-2' after being changed.

My second issue is with the custom post type 'Case Study' which ties into this page. I can get the page to pull the custom posts in a list, but their permalink goes to a 404 and resetting the permalink structure didn't fix it!

Lastly, my attempts to resolve this problem have led to my Case Studies page bouncing back to the homepage no matter what I do with the template file.

Thanks in advance folks,
Graham

Answer (score 1):

The first page of Case Study with nav-structure `case-studies` is still available in trash of post so firstly delete that page from trash & then edit your new case study page and in that edit permalink and remove 2 just like `case-studies-2` to `case-studies`

For second issue you have to register your custom post type to theme's function.php file

For this add this code to `function.php` file

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'album', 'movies','music_review') );

    return $query;
}
```

after this reset your permalink

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Deleting the old file from the bin resolved my '-2' suffix issue, so thank you for helping with this!

I tried adding the code in to functions.php, and included my "case-study" custom post type in the array but it hasn't worked, unfortunately.

the /case-studies link is broken, even when clicking the preview link from the Post Edit page. Tweaking it allows it to display, but as before the links all point to a non-existant page which redirects me to the homepage.

Any further ideas?

Comment: just do reseting your permalink 1 or 2 times..many times this issue is coming & it's related to permalink..

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved - the old file was in the bin, not properly removed. Deleting it from there allowed me to update the permalink directly on the page :)

Thanks for your help, peeps!